# EventStore batch event reading from $all via gRPC

Tags: grpc, event-sourcing, eventstoredb, event-store

An application is written on `C#`, is trying to use `EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams` version 23.1.0 to access `EventStore`.

```
var positionToRead = startFromPosition == 0 ? Position.Start : new Position(startFromPosition, startFromPosition);
var readStreamAsync = _client.ReadAllAsync(Direction.Forwards, positionToRead, take);
```

When the last event is received, the application knows its Position. let's imagine it's 777.
After that application restarted, when it was restarting, another event was written to `EventStore`, let's imagine it's position 1111.

How to continue reading from the new (1111) event?

If you try to use position 778 during `ReadAllAsync` (expecting it indicates your goal to read events after 777)- the application throws an exception, I guess it's because the next event position is 1111 and you need to know the precise position 1111.

How to read event A from $all, after certain event B, if you don't know the position of A, but you know that position B is higher than position A ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to *read* from $all, you need to use a valid commit position. You can't use `778` because commit position is not a sequential number of an event in $all, it's more like an offset in the global log. It's confusing, but that's how it is.

Reading from $all is not a common as you'd normally subscribe to $all to receive events as they are appended to the database. Subscription to $all starts from the next event after the start position you provide. In addition, subscriptions allow you to filter out events on the server, like system events. When reading from $all, you will get system events alongside with the actual data events.

If you, for some reason, need to read from $all, I can suggest that if the start position is not `Position.Start`, you deliberately skip one event when iterating through the async enumerable.